# How to stop one thread after completion of other?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Thread th=new Thread()
        {

            public void run(){

                for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
                    System.out.println("run:"+i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }   

            }};
            Thread y=new Thread()
            {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                        System.out.println("stop:"+i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }   

                }

            };

            th.start();
            y.start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("main:"+i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }

            }
            System.out.println("main completed");
    }   

}
```

Here i want to stop Thread th as soon as thread y completes its execution,how can I do that?

Comment: You can have one thread interrupt the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ***volatile boolean variable*** and set it to ***false***. After the completion of thread y make it ***true***. On the condition check stop the desired thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the main processing of main thread until thread y is complete and then stop the th thread. 
Use the following:

```
y.join();
th.kill(); \\ Create a custom kill method which stops the thread. Check code.
```

You may also take a look at CountDownLatch which can be used to address such situations. 
Use the following code:

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean run_th = true;
        Thread th=new Thread()
        {

            public void run(){
                while(run_th) {
                  for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
                       System.out.println("run:"+i);
                       try {
                           Thread.sleep(1000);
                       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       }
                   } 
                }      
            }
            public void kill() {
               run_th = false; 
            }

         };
            Thread y=new Thread()
            {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                        System.out.println("stop:"+i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }   

                }

            };

            th.start();
            y.start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("main:"+i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }
            }
            y.join();
            th.kill();
            System.out.println("main completed");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do not use the stop method, it's Deprecated.

Comment: ... for a good reason. You don't want to stop a thread, you want to (gracefully) stop the activities that the thread is performing and as a result of that the thread itself will stop.

Answer (score 0):

at principle level, use a flag that thread Y sets before finishing, and thread TH checks it every time. When thread Y sets it to true or false and thread TH reads that change, then you can stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {


       final Thread th=new Thread()
        {

            public void run(){

                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println("run:"+i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }   

            }};
            Thread y=new Thread()
            {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                        System.out.println("stop:"+i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }   
                    th.stop();
                }

            };

            th.start();
            y.start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                System.out.println("main:"+i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }

            }
            System.out.println("main completed");
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         Thread th=new Thread()
                {

                 public void run(){

            for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
                            if(y.isAlive()){
                                System.out.println("run:"+i);
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                }

            }else{
      this.stop();
}
    }


                    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volatile variable and use it in the execution to create dependencies in between thread:

```
package com.test;

class ThreadDependency {
    volatile static boolean isYCompleted = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread th = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
                    if(!isYCompleted) {
                        System.out.println("run:" + i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread y = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println("stop:" + i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                    if(i == 9) {
                        isYCompleted = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        th.start();
        y.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("main:" + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        System.out.println("Main completed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here i want to stop Thread th as soon as thread y completes its
>   execution,how can I do that?

Java has provided you exactly the method you need.  All you need to do is fill in your "TODO" blocks.

Quoting from the JDK documentation for the [interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) method:

> Interrupts this thread.
>
> ... [snip]
>
> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.

So, thread `y` can call the interrupt method on the thread `th` and cause it to receive an `InterruptedException`.  That's exactly why those checks are there for the `sleep()` calls.  Now, just fill them in and you'll have exactly what you need:

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread th=new Thread()
        {
            public void run(){
                for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
                    System.out.println("run:"+i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        // Here is one way that you can immediately exit th
                        System.out.println("Thread th was interrupted.");
                        System.out.println("y must have finished");
                        break;
                        // This will immediately exit the loop 
                        // and the run method

                    }
                }   

            }};
            Thread y=new Thread()
            {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                        System.out.println("stop:"+i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }

                    // Here is where we trigger the end of thread th
                    System.out.println("y is finished.  Interrupting th.");
                    th.interrupt();
                    // th will receive the InterruptedException
                } 
            };

            th.start();
            y.start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("main:"+i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
            }
            System.out.println("main completed");
    }   
}
```

The moral of the story is: look at those auto-generated catch blocks - maybe that's where you should start.